# add link of custom module to user dashboard magento

Tags: magento

can someone tell me how to add a link of custom module to user dashbord left navigation in magento. I tried to add

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
                <name>account_view</name>
                <path>customer/account/view/</path>
                <label>Account Details</label>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

in my layout xml file but it is not working

thanks

Comment: What version of Magento are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
            <name>yournamespace_yourmodule</name>
            <path>module/controller/action</path>
            <label>Label</label>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

Comment: Which is the file in which you added this code ? Always add full description in your answer. Thanks